# Flutter register native ad factory

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies, firebase-admob

I'm reading this doc: https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_admob

But I don't understand this:

> This is done slightly differently depending on whether you are using
> Embedding V1 or Embedding V2

How do I know that?

Also I found a MainActivity.kt with this content:

```
package com.drodriguez.my_rents

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.plugins.GeneratedPluginRegistrant

import android.os.Build
import android.view.ViewTreeObserver
import android.view.WindowManager
class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    override fun configureFlutterEngine(@NonNull flutterEngine: FlutterEngine) {
        GeneratedPluginRegistrant.registerWith(flutterEngine);
    }
}
```

but it's not a .java

Answer (score 0):

In your AndroidManifest.xml file you will find the entry:

```
<meta-data
  android:name="flutterEmbedding"
  android:value="2" />
```

That will tell you about which Embedding version your project is using.
Most likely it will be version 2, as this is the standard since FLutter version 1.2.

See also for reference:
[Android v1 embedding app and plugin creation deprecation](https://flutter.dev/docs/release/breaking-changes/android-v1-embedding-create-deprecation)

Regarding the firebase_admob package:
With the arrival of Flutter 2 and null-safety I would propose you use the new google_mobile_ads pacakge.
[google_mobile_ads](https://pub.dev/packages/google_mobile_ads)

The old package will become deprecated soon.

Comment: Interesting that you mentioned the deprecated part. Flutter's team didn't mention this anywhere. The problem I have with the new package is this: https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-flutter/issues/43#issuecomment-795204830

Comment: Not sure if that will solve your problem, but I also had to refer to their examples to get the Ads display correctly. The docs are missing some parts.
[Examples in Github](https://github.com/googleads/googleads-mobile-flutter/blob/master/packages/google_mobile_ads/example/lib/main.dart)

Comment: Oh and when you open the [old package's site](https://pub.dev/packages/firebase_admob), you will see in the red box 'DISCONTINUED' ^^

Comment: yeah, they added that recently